# BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter not working on kernel 5.11 and ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, kernel, broadcom

Right now it works with kernel 5.8 but in 5.11 (installed this morning along other upgrades) the wifi adapter doesn't get detected at all and apparently there are no fixes until the drivers gets patched (unless i'm mistaken). Do someone know if/when `bcmwl-kernel-source` will get patched?

edit: current version of `bcmwl-kernel-source` is `6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7`

PS: To be honest each time there's a kernel upgrade this adapter stops working... it's quite frustrating

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel options; the GA kernel is static for those wanting a *stable* system (it's the default for servers), or the HWE kernel choice (default for Ubuntu Desktop) for those wanting later *drivers* (ie. kernel modules) which get updated.  If you want *stability*, why not switch to the GA kernel stack?   FYI:  You can even have both installed; so if you have issues with one, you've still got the other to boot with (selected at `grub`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'll look into it :)

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  & https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i solved the issue by downloading a binary (deb) from here: [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7%7E20.04.3)

I uninstalled what i had, and installed `bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_20.04.3_amd64.deb` which was backported from Irsute Hippo which installs kernel 5.11 by default.

Before i had solved a similar issue from 5.4 to 5.8 by installing this binary `bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb`

Same version basically but fixed for 5.11. Probably that's why apt said i had the latest version installed (which was truish).

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the same symptom of my BCM4313. The …~20.04.3 version is (now?) in the focal repositories, so I only had to install that particular version with `apt install bcmwl-kernel-source=6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3`. Now it works fine under 5.11.x kernels. [Still I don't get why it was not offered before as a security update, then apt declared i was **downgrading** the package version when force-installed, and now the previously installed version is not offered as a newer package…]